# how to add/remove change 'disabled' or 'checked' attribute using angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was looking to toggle a switch(also disable) using check box,and I came across html attributes checked/enabled, it works fine if I type it into the code it works well, but I am not able to figure out is how to control it dynamically using angularjs. I tried the code below for disabling I used

```
<input type="checkbox" value={{light.status}} ng-click="toggle(light.status)" enabled />
```

for checked I used,

```
<input type="checkbox"   value={{light.status}} ng-click="toggle(light.status)" checked/>
```

I tried

```
<input type="checkbox"   value={{light.status}} ng-click="toggle(light.status)" {{status}}/>
```

angular part of the same

```
  function toggelingtype(type){
  if(type==1}$scope.status="checked";
  if(type==2)  $scope.status="";
  if(type==3)$scope.status="disabled;
```

this function is called when some http request I received

Comment: `if(type==3)$scope.status="disabled;` is missing ending quotes. Is that the issue? Should be `if(type==3)$scope.status="disabled";`

Comment: sorry i miss typed it ,this not the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use attributes like `ng-checked` and `ng-disabled`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="light.checked" ng-disabled="light.disabled" />
```

**EDIT**: Alternative

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="light.status" ng-disabled="!light.status" />
```

Now if you set `light.status = false;`, the checkbox will be both unchecked and disabled.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but i was thinking that is there any method to add attribute like disabled and checked to the html tag using angular

Comment: @KaranSinghKochar checkbox already has attributes like disabled and checked, why do you want to add ?

Comment: i meant using those '{{}}' inside an html tag like <button {{state}}></button> and changing it like $scope.state=enabled;

Comment: can you suggest how to use ng-checked and ng-disabled in ng-repeat because it is setting the property to all

Comment: @KaranSinghKochar use `$index` inside `ng-repeat` to achieve that.